# Files from my home directory not found in cygwin terminal

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, mintty

I'm trying to setup cygwin, but it does not work out of the box.
Now I cannot use files from my home directory :

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Users/jb/test
$ ls
t
$ ls t 
t
$ ls ~/test/t
ls: File or directory "/cygdrive/c/Users/jb/test/t" is not found
$ ls /cygdrive/c/Users/jb/test/t
ls: File or directory "/cygdrive/c/Users/jb/test/t" is not found
```

Any ideas what is wrong? How is that my home directory is not found even if I'm in it?

Comment: `ls t` gives `t`, so maybe you have to go to `t/t/`

Comment: But `pwd` states that the path mentioned should exist...

Comment: Bash was not run with --login. Now it works fine.

Comment: Interesting. Why does it actually matter if you provide a full path?

Answer (score 0):

Have you not, by any chance, removed it? Try

```
cd ..
cd test
```

and see if it works.

Your current shell can see a directory it's in, but it wouldn't be able to see it "from the outside".

That's a guess of course, but give it a try.